# How to fetch value from a list stored in a ViewBag as options(value) in a select element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, viewbag

I have few items in Viewbag as a list:

```
 var days = new List<SelectListItem>();
        days.Add(new SelectListItem
        {   Text = "Monday", Value = "Monday" });
        days.Add(new SelectListItem
        {   Text = "Tuesday", Value = "Tuesday" });
        days.Add(new SelectListItem
        {   Text = "Wednesday", Value = "Wednesday" });
        days.Add(new SelectListItem
        {   Text = "Thursday", Value = "Thursday" });
        days.Add(new SelectListItem
        {   Text = "Friday", Value = "Friday" });

        ViewBag.DayItems = days;
```

I can easily pass this value to the view class using html helper generated during scaffolding in this way:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Days, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Days, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DayItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Days, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I have a html select element:

```
<select>
    <option value="@Value=ViewBag.DayItems"></option>
</select>
```

,where I want to pass the days from ViewBag as value. How should I include **ViewBag.DayItems**?

Comment: Not clear what you asking. Why don't you want to use the `DropDownListFor()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below approach works for me:

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedDay", ViewBag.DayItems as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

A rather classical approach would be:

```
<select>
    @{ 
        foreach (var day in ViewBag.DayItems as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
        {
            <option  value="@day.Value">@day.Text</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Comment: even more:  `@if(dat.Selected){<option  value="@day.Value" selected='selected'>@day.Text</option>}else{...}`

Comment: @Marcin The OP didn't provide any selection info.

Comment: Yes, but it can be full answer, not in this particular problem. Because SelectListItem can pass selection info if it will be set.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's missing optional label, try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Days, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DayItems, "Select one", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Add an optional string 'Select one' or whatever you want from resources.